# Java Program Design - Card Shuffler

Tags: java, oop, hashset, design-principles, sortedset

I am trying to write a **card shuffler**, and I know the method by which I wish to shuffle the cards.  However, I am at a loss of the best object-oriented way in which to write it.

The method, a rather common one, is as follows:

- Assign each a random numeric value, between 0 and 2,147,483,647
- If there is a duplicate key value (very unlikely), throw away the deck, and start again.
- Store the cards in a set
- Order the set by each cards key value

My problem lies in the best OOP way to write this.  At first I came up with an object called `Card`, containing a suit value, a number value and the random key value.  Then I would have a class called `Deck` that extended a `HashSet`, and I would store each card into the `HashSet` and then sort it by key value.  Where I struggled was, what is the most efficient way to 'generate' the 52 `Card` objects in the first place, and how to order the set.  Would I implement the interface, 'SortedSet', if so, how would I go about writing the comparators?

Quite a broad question, more based on OOP design practices, but I'd like this to be a really smooth and *object based solution*.

Cheers,

Tim.

EDIT:

Thanks for the help everyone.  My solution was as follows:

- 2 Enums (CardValues, CardSuits), containing the 4 suits and 13 possible values
- Card class, that takes as constructor arguments a CardValue and a CardSuit.
- Deck class that extends a TreeMap

When a new deck is created and shuffled, I loop through the CardSuit Enum and created Cards, then inside that loop, I go through the CardValue Enum.  This creates the cards, I then generate a random key and put them in the TreeMap.

As there is always a small chance of key repetition, if the final deck size is not 52, I throw a new InvalidDeckException.

Thanks for the suggestions, I am much happier with this solution.

Comment: You can just check if the key is already in the map with `containsKey()` and then generate a new if needed, instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: Yeah I did have that implemented at first, but I thought seeing how rare it could actually occur and from a performance aspect (if this code was running thousands of times a minute), throwing an exception when it does happen, is better than checking every time.  What do you think?

Comment: You'd have to benchmark to see. Either way i think it's moot, because it's a retarded way to shuffle. [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) (`Collections.shuffle()`) is better and likely faster, and doesn't have the issue with random number conflicts.

Comment: Why would I use a List if there would never be duplicate elements? By using Collections.shuffle() I have zero control over the efficiency of the algorithm at all. Plus, the Fisher-Yates is an O(n) algorithm, my implementation, as I am using a set rather than a list requires no sorting - meaning less strain on memory.  And if I did want to assign values then make the sort, I could easily implement the sort as a QuickSort or MergeSort making it O(n log n).  Both ways are quicker than the F-Y shuffle. This question wasn't about the shuffling algorithm, it was about an OO design of a shuffle.

Comment: You can't do better on shuffle than O(n). You would use a list because it keeps track of the order of the elements and is simple  to work with. Your method will use more memory, with TreeMap entries pointing to integers and cards in addition to the HashSet. I don't know what sorting has to do with this. Fisher-Yates doesn't sort, it shuffles. I hope you know O(n) is more efficient than O(n log n).

Comment: Sorting and shuffling are synonymous in this case.  You are assigning an element a position in the list and moving it, you are sorting it into a randomly specified order.  O(n) is not more efficient that O(n log n), how can that possibly make sense?  If that was the case, why is QuickSort a more effective sort than Insertion Sort?  This is besides the point.  I guess there must be a reason why the majority of all gambling websites use the random number method to shuffle their cards rather than the Fisher-Yates approach.

Comment: Fisher-Yates has to visit each list index once. It's a loop from 1 to n-1. It's easy to see that the only time a quick sort only needs to visit each list index once is when the list is already sorted, otherwise it will visit more than n list indices. Think about it.

Comment: To quote [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Comparison_with_other_shuffling_algorithms): "The Fisher–Yates shuffle is quite efficient; indeed, its asymptotic time and space complexity are optimal."

Comment: I don't think you quite understand Big O Notation, or complexity.  There is a reason Quicksort is one of the most widely used sorting algorithms - it has an average complexity of O(n log n).  Which is the equivalent of log(n!), take n to be 10. Then we have O(10) and O(6.5), I know which one I'd rather use.  Like I said before, there must be a reason why audited GAMBLING websites, who take efficiency very seriously, use the assign an element a number method over the Fisher-Yates. Not saying Fisher-Yates is bad at all, I just don't want the stack overhead of sorting a list (into a random order)

Comment: Yeah, i'm aware that i misused Big O Notation slightly, sorry. I want a citation on your claim that no gambling websites use Fisher-Yates. http://www.pokerstars.com/poker/room/features/security/ claims to use Sattolo's algorithm, a variation of Fisher-Yates. http://www.royalpokeronline.com/shuffling.htm uses Fisher-Yates in addition to your method. http://www.frogpoker.com/security.php claims to use Fisher-Yates. You'll be doing more work and getting more stack overhead with your method. A sort requires one or more passes. Fisher-Yates is a shuffle, and requires just exactly one pass.

Comment: Also http://www.gamedaypoker.com/dice-and-card-shuffling.php claims to use Fisher-Yates.

Comment: Sorry, I originally put 'majority of sites', but in the most recent post, I didn't.  PKR http://www.pkr.com/en/support/licensing-and-integrity/monthly-certificates/, PartyPoker http://www.partypoker.com/about_us/game-fairness-and-security/random-number-generator.html, WilliamHill http://poker.williamhill.com/help/rng-certification/ All of use the mapping of numbers method.  PKR seems to use an array, then they sort it.  Rather than using a map, the others aren't described in as much detail.  Most websites describe their RNG, as the shuffle is pretty trivial in comparison.

Comment: Your claim was that audited gambling websites don't use Fisher-Yates, because of performance, resource use, and possibly other factors. I refuted that. The only reason they would be using something else in addition is if the software doing the Fisher-Yates shuffle would be compromised. As Wikipedia says, "The Fisher–Yates shuffle is quite efficient; indeed, its asymptotic time and space complexity are optimal." I stand by my claim that your way to shuffle is retarded when Fisher-Yates exists, and i also claim it generally should use more resources and be less performant than Fisher-Yates.

Comment: No that wasn't my claim, I said "I guess there must be a reason why", in other words, I wonder why some sites use that.  There is no reason to say this method is retarded when it used in industry, by extremely successful, efficient and fast gambling software.  I still don't understand why you are differentiating between sorting and shuffling, it is the same thing.  You give an element a position, you move it to that position - that is what sorting does.  My approach does not need to sort as everything is placed the first time in the correct spot.

Comment: If I used an ArrayList instead of a TreeMap and then sorted, this approach, O(n log n) would actually be more efficient than the O(n) Fisher-Yates approach.  In terms of memory, Fisher-Yates isn't an in-place sort/shuffle.  Collections.shuffle() will make a lot of calls onto the stack, and use of memory when ran.  We can see this when we run it and debug.  In terms of overall effective shuffling, both are as adequate as the seed they are provided with.

Comment: I am quite happy using a method for my application that is being used by businesses who turnover millions in profit each year with their audited software.

Comment: The point is that for 99.99% of your use cases, `Collections.shuffle()` is enough. The retarded part is writing your own code for something that's in the standard library. Also, note that Fisher-Yates always does exactly 51 swaps for a deck, while a sort will *always* make *at least* 51 swaps. O(n) is definitely better than O(n log n).

Comment: The difference between sorting and shuffling is that shuffling always requires exactly one pass, while sorting will always make more than one pass unless it's already sorted. Shuffling generates random numbers, sorting does not. The best you can do with shuffling is O(n), the best you can do with sorting except for special cases is O(n log n). Sorting compares elements, shuffling does not. Huge differences.

Comment: Fisher-Yates is definitely an in-place shuffle, and implemented as such in `Collections.shuffle()`. It also places each element in its correct spot the first time. Fisher-Yates isn't recursive, so i have no idea what you mean with "lots of calls onto the stack". There will certainly not be less method calls in your method, not to mention a whole bunch of compares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `TreeMap`, for each card generate a random number that doesn't exist in the map, and insert it in the map as the key for the card, done.

The map is now ordered by the random numbers generated.

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuffling#Shuffling_algorithms

Note that this is a retarded way to shuffle, just use `Collections.shuffle()`.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote some poker analysis stuff.  I created an Enum for all the card types, with `rank` and `value` fields.  I then initialized all 52 card enum possibilities.  So yes, I had 52 enum defs (and a separate enum for all possible 2-card starting hands -- sometimes brute force is the best option)

I then created a `Deck` class that had a `List` of `Enum<Card>` types.

Initializing the Deck is as simple as generating an `EnumSet` of the Enum, and passing that set to a List.  You can then put your `shuffle` method on the `Deck` class and have it use the list for the Deck.

The advantage of this is you only ever have 52 cards in your app -- its like the FlyWeight pattern.

Comment: What I've done is, created two Enums, one for suit, one for value.  This reduces the number of constants and repetition.  I then am able to nest two loops and pass the Enums as parameters to my Card object.

Answer (score 1):

**Card.java**:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Card {
    public enum Rank { DEUCE, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX,
        SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING, ACE }

    public enum Suit { CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES }

    private final Rank rank;
    private final Suit suit;
    private Card(Rank rank, Suit suit) {
        this.rank = rank;
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    public Rank rank() { return rank; }
    public Suit suit() { return suit; }
    public String toString() { return rank + " of " + suit; }

    private static final List<Card> protoDeck = new ArrayList<Card>();

    // Initialize prototype deck
    static {
        for (Suit suit : Suit.values())
            for (Rank rank : Rank.values())
                protoDeck.add(new Card(rank, suit));
    }

    public static ArrayList<Card> newDeck() {
        return new ArrayList<Card>(protoDeck); // Return copy of prototype deck
    }
}
```

**Deal.java** :

```
import java.util.*;

public class Deal {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int numHands = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int cardsPerHand = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        List<Card> deck  = Card.newDeck();
        Collections.shuffle(deck);
        for (int i=0; i < numHands; i++)
            System.out.println(deal(deck, cardsPerHand));
    }

    public static ArrayList<Card> deal(List<Card> deck, int n) {
         int deckSize = deck.size();
         List<Card> handView = deck.subList(deckSize-n, deckSize);
         ArrayList<Card> hand = new ArrayList<Card>(handView);
         handView.clear();
         return hand;
     }
}
```

**Output:**

```
 $ java Deal 4 5
    [FOUR of HEARTS, NINE of DIAMONDS, QUEEN of SPADES, ACE of SPADES, NINE of SPADES]
    [DEUCE of HEARTS, EIGHT of SPADES, JACK of DIAMONDS, TEN of CLUBS, SEVEN of SPADES]
    [FIVE of HEARTS, FOUR of DIAMONDS, SIX of DIAMONDS, NINE of CLUBS, JACK of CLUBS]
    [SEVEN of HEARTS, SIX of CLUBS, DEUCE of DIAMONDS, THREE of SPADES, EIGHT of CLUBS]
```

**Reference**:

- [Enum Usage Example](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html).

Answer (score 1):

I would define the Card as a class holding the Suite and the number value. The Card shouldn't have any knowledge of the random number associated.

The Deck is a class containing a List of Cards and having the shuffle method, by use of the random numbers which maybe don't need to be stored somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)

See the above doc for shuffle method in java.util.Collections util class.

```
 class Card {

private int number;
// other attributes
```

}

and simply use:-

```
Collections.shuffle(listOfCards);
```

Comment: Thanks, although this is simple, it removes the ability for me to control how my shuffling algorithm works.  I'd rather be handling that myself.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing is just assign a value attribute to the card types and sort on that (face cards J,Q,K,A->11,12,13, 14) .  Ordering suits you'd have to pick some arbitrary order and organize into a "Pack" of cards which has a sorted set of each suit.  Since the suits never change, the Pack always has a sorted set of each Clubs, Hearts, Diamonds, and Spades.

Generating the cards? Each pack obviously has to define 4 suits. Have a CardFactory that generates and returns a full set for each suit, given the Suit.  The Factory would just blindly generate the 2-10 and face cards and return the sorted set.

Answer (score 0):

You should not get into the `Card` class data that is not particular of a given card. In particular, the order inside a deck and the random number is not an attribute of the card (the card is the same no matter where in the deck it is).

The card attributes should be just its value and state (shown/hidden). The deck may be implemented with a List. Shuffling would be just a method from Deck.

For shuffling there are several options:

1) you list the random numbers by themselves and order them; each change in the random number list is reproduced in the card list. The issue is that you cannot use the sort methods already available for List()

2) You add an intermediate class (lets call it ShufCard) that contains both a Card and the random number, and either:

a) The deck is a list of these intermediate objects.

b) For shuffling, you create a temporal list with the contents of the decks, shuffle, and then retrieve the cards from the temporal list mantaining its order. Something like:

```
 List<ShufCard> list = new ArrayList<ShufCard>();
 for (Card card : Deck.cards) {
   list.add(new ShufCard(Card, Random.getNumber());
 }

 list.sort();
 Deck.cards.clear();

 for (ShufCard shCard : list) {
   Deck.cards.add(shCard.getCard());
 }
```